Error: Inconsistent Dependency Lock File with AWS Provider in GitLab CI/CD Pipeline
I'm using GitLab CI/CD to run my terraform pipeline. I have 4 stages

Copy a File Stage
Terraform Init
Terraform Plan
Terraform Apply

Here is my provider information:
  terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }

Here are the stages of my gitlab ci file:
copy-files:
  stage: copy-files
  script: 
    - make copy-files

terraform-init: 
  stage: terraform-init
  script:
    - make terraform-init
  dependencies:
    - copy-files

terraform-plan: 
  stage: terraform-plan
  script:
    - make terraform-plan
  dependencies:
    - terraform-init

As you can see I use Make commands to run commands:
# Copy Command
copy-files: 
    @echo "Copying file providers.tf and variables.tf to stack"
    @cp $(GENERIC_VARIABLES_DIR) $(TF_DIR)
    @cp $(GENERIC_PROVIDERS_DIR) $(TF_DIR)

# Initialize Terraform
terraform-init:
    @echo "Initializing environment..."
    terraform -chdir=$(TF_DIR) init -upgrade
    terraform validate

# Plan command for the environment
terraform-plan:
    @echo "Running terraform plan for environment..."
    terraform -chdir=$(TF_DIR) plan -var-file="variables.tfvars"

# Apply command for the environment
terraform-apply:
    @echo "Running terraform apply..."
    terraform -chdir=$(TF_DIR) apply -auto-approve -var-file="variables.tfvars"

It Initilizes successfully but when it gets to the Terraform Plan I'm getting the following error:
The following dependency selections recorded in the lock file are
minconsistent with the current configuration:
- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws: required by this configuration but no version is selected

To make the initial dependency selections that will initialize the
mdependency lock file, run: terraform init

I'm unsure what I need to do, I did wonder if it's because every stage clones the repo and this causes the issue due to .terraform.lock.hcl not existing.
Any suggestions?

Do you have a .terraform.lock file in your repository?

I do not, I guess I would need to run my make commands locally to generate a .terraform.lock?

Sorry, it's .terraform.lock.hcl. Which terraform version are you using locally and in the pipeline?

I have not ran this locally. Just running in the pipeline I'm using version 1.9.3 - linux_amd64

You should have the lock file for new terraform versions. It is basically like the package-lock.json in Node for example. It is important to have since it provides consistency. For example, when you run the terraform init command with -upgrade option it will try to update the provider versions to the latest ones. Sometimes it can break things and this way you have no control over what happens.

One soution is to run locally terraform init once to generate the .terraform.lock.hcl file. Push this file to the repository which helps a lot in consistency and speed. This file is a dependency lock file. Then removing the terraform-init job from pipeline. Seems that upgrade is making the trouble.

I've ran locally and generated a terraform.lock.hcl file, now I'm getting the following error when using the pipeline:
The installed provider plugins are not consistent with the packages
│ selected in the dependency lock file:
│   - registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws: there is no package for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws 5.63.0 cached in .terraform/providers
